# Deadlock -- Way to make this better?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, update, deadlock

I have this query that deadlocks every once in a while. It is doing a self update to a table. ( update, from ) Is there any better way to handle the concurrency?
Here is the plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r19CZMC8-

Deadlock:

  
    
  
  
    
      
        
UPDATE j SET StatusId=@StatusId -- SELECT * 
FROM jobmanager.JobRun j with(rowlock) WHERE PrintBatchId=@PrintBatchI    
      
      
Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 191196327]

Comment: That query by itself can't cause deadlock so you need to figure out what more is involved in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would try to understand why your query leads to a deadlock. It would be useful to look at deadlock graph info. Try enabling trace flags (1204, 1222) to get more details from the SQL Server log.
2. Since you are using the row level locking and get deadlocks I suspect that PrintBatchId might have a large number of records associated. So SQL Server has to escalate the lock to page/table level. And as a result, you get a deadlock with an update on different PrintBatchId. (BTW. Do you have an index on PrintBatchId? W/o proper index row level locking won't work). Try to make query filter smaller.
3. If you can't make your filter more precise I would suggest to catch deadlocks and retry update attempt. Here is a sample code:

   ```
   DECLARE @Retries INT = 5
       , @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max)
       , @ErrorLine INT    
       , @ErrorSeverity INT
       , @ErrorNumber INT 

   WHILE (@Retries > 0)
   BEGIN             
       BEGIN TRY
           --UPDATE Command.... 
           SELECT @retries = 0
       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
           SELECT 
                 @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
               , @ErrorLine    = ERROR_LINE()
               , @ErrorSeverity= ERROR_SEVERITY()
               , @ErrorNumber  = ERROR_NUMBER();

           IF (@ErrorNumber = 1205 AND @Retries > 0) -- If Deadlock, then retry 
               SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Execution Failed due to a deadlock. Retrying... ';
           ELSE
           IF (@ErrorNumber = 1205 AND @Retries <= 0) -- If Deadlock, and max number of retries reached. Fail.
               SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Execution Failed due to a deadlock after max number of retries ... ' + CHAR(13) + ' Original Error: Msg. ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + @ErrorMessage;
           ELSE
               SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Execution Failed: Msg ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + @ErrorMessage;

           SELECT @Retries-=1;     

       END CATCH;
   END
   ```

Comment: Alexander, yesterday I updated the post with the deadlock plan. Maybe it isn't there? Either way I will update the proc with your retry logic and push through our dev cycle.

Comment: Alexander can you see the deadlock plan?

Comment: DECLARE @IsError bit SELECT @IsError=IsError FROM jobmanager.Status WHERE StatusID=@StatusId

--Set Error state on batch:
UPDATE b SET StatusId=@StatusId,ErrorDttm=case when @IsError=1 then getdate() end -- SELECT * 
FROM jobmanager.PrintBatch b with(rowlock) WHERE PrintBatchId=@PrintBatchId

UPDATE j SET StatusId=@StatusId -- SELECT * 
FROM jobmanager.JobRun j with(rowlock) WHERE PrintBatchId=@PrintBatchId

Comment: I see this: "Deadlock: UPDATE j SET StatusId=@StatusId -- SELECT * FROM jobmanager.JobRun j with(rowlock) WHERE PrintBatchId=@PrintBatchI Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 191196327]" on your main message. But this information is not sufficient.

Comment: On the other hand I took another look at the execution plan. I see that you the second query does the Clustered Index Scan. What is the structure of the jobmanagerJobRun.PK_JobRun index? Why does it scan it? It is most likely affecting locking.

Comment: Alexander, All this time I wasn't looking at the 2nd update. I thought the blocking was done by the first update in the proc. I added an nc index to the jobrun table this morning. So far no more deadlocks. Still trying to figure out how to add the deadlock xml to the question.

Comment: Glad that the issue is resolved. Do you mind accepting my answer (clicking on the check next to my answer)? Of course only if you think that my input was helpful. Thanks.